# how to search a string+ip address and print it if it finds it

Tags: python, python-3.x

### i have the below file:

address-family ipv4 vrf vrf1

redistribute eigrp 252 route-map vrf1

neighbor 10.1.1.1 remote-as 2

neighbor 10.1.1.1 description to_ebgp

neighbor 10.1.1.1 update-source Vlan2

neighbor 10.1.1.1 activate

neighbor 10.1.1.1 send-community both

neighbor 10.1.1.1 soft-reconfiguration inbound

neighbor 10.1.1.1 route-map INBOUND in

neighbor 10.1.1.1 route-map OUTBOUND out

exit-address-family

---

i want to write something that opens this file, read it and anytime it finds "neighbor [ip] route-map INBOUND in" print it on the terminal.

Moved your code from comments section to the question for easier access to your code:

```
import re  
filepath = 'run_bgp.txt'  
ip = re.compile(r'(^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)') 
with open(filepath) as fp:
    filestring = fp.readlines()
    for line in filestring:
        x = line.split(' ')
        if x[0] == 'neighbor' and x[1] == re.compile(r'(^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)') and x[2] == 'route-map' and x[3] == 'INBOUND' and x[4] == 'in':
            print(' '.join(x))


import re

data = ""
with open("run_bgp.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data += line


result = re.search("neighbor.*route-map INBOUND in", data).group()
print(result)
```

Comment: Try using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: i use the regex but it only finds it, i dont know how to print it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution, using `all`

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    filter_ = ['neighbor', 'route-map', 'INBOUND', 'in']

    for x in f.readlines():
        if all(f in x for f in filter_):
            print(x)
```

---

```
neighbor 10.1.1.1 route-map INBOUND in
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method One**

[Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

**Method Two**

[Splitting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Assuming a single line is assigned to a variable (x in our example).

```
x = x.split(' ')
if x[0] == 'neighbor' and x[2] == 'route-map' and x[3] == 'INBOUND' and x[4] == 'in':
    print(' '.join(x))
```

Comment: @user2251348,  I moved your code to the question. It is best to show up there

Answer (score 0):

If the result format is the same as described in the question, you can use regex to extract the result something like:

```
data = ""
with open("filename", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data += line

import re
        
result = re.search("neighbor.*route-map INBOUND in", data).group()
print(result)
```

the result would be:

```
neighbor 10.1.1.1 route-map INBOUND in
```

Comment: @sushanth now if i want to know the line that was found and printed belonged to "address-family ipv4 vrf1" how can i include that

Comment: @Ahmad_R the result you are expecting is inside result variable. You can just print the result using print(result) and you will get the required output.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
it errors out when i print the result

Comment: did you replace the file name with the absolute path of your file?

Comment: i am not sure why i get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`